# Javascript Replacing Spaces within an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace

I'm ok at PHP, but no nothing about Javascript, so I have no idea how to proceed here. I'm trying to replace spaces with a "+" in line 3.  Anybody know why it's not working?  Thanks!

```
var tn_dv_suggestions = new Array();
for(var tn_counter=0; tn_counter < tn_top_performers.length; tn_counter++)
tn_top_performers[tn_counter]=tn_top_performers[tn_counter].replace(" ","+");
tn_dv_suggestions.push("<a style='font-family: Verdana, Arial; font-size: 14px;' target='_blank' href='http://www.<?=$siterow['Domain']?>/Buy-"+escape(tn_top_performers[tn_counter]) +"-<?=urlencode($siterow['CitySearchName'])?>-Tickets' >"+tn_top_performers[tn_counter] +"</a><br />");
document.getElementById('tn_dv_suggestions089hZ').innerHTML=tn_dv_suggestions.join('');
```

Comment: Can you give us some example input (values in tn_top_performers before the loop) and output (values in tn_top_performers after the loop)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of String.replace() is fine. The problem is that you are missing curly brackets surrounding all of the statements you want in the loop.

Fixed code:

```
var tn_dv_suggestions = new Array();
for (var tn_counter=0; tn_counter < tn_top_performers.length; tn_counter++) {
  tn_top_performers[tn_counter]=tn_top_performers[tn_counter].replace(" ","+");
  tn_dv_suggestions.push("<a style='font-family: Verdana, Arial; font-size: 14px;' target='_blank' href='http://www.<?=$siterow['Domain']?>/Buy-"+escape(tn_top_performers[tn_counter]) +"-<?=urlencode($siterow['CitySearchName'])?>-Tickets' >"+tn_top_performers[tn_counter] +"</a><br />");
}
document.getElementById('tn_dv_suggestions089hZ').innerHTML=tn_dv_suggestions.join('');
```

Comment: That did it!  Thanks so much for noticing that!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using array.map:

```
var replaceInArray = function(str){
  return str.replace(/\s+/g, "+")
}

var arr = ["Summer is Great", "Winter is terrible"]

arr.map(replaceInArray);
// returns => ["Summer+is+Great", "Winter+is+terrible"]
```

Your problem was that you were only replacing the first instance of " ". To fix this, use the global flag, by using `g` with your regex.

Answer (score 1):

you probably replace only first space found. to replace all of them, you'll need `global` flag. try `.replace(/\ /g, "+");`

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I just tried that, but it only displays "undefined"

Comment: well, the replace itself is fine then. your problem must be somewhere else - possibly `tn_top_performers[tn_counter]` is undefined?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm pretty green at javascript.  When I take out the replace line, the results are displayed fine (but still of course have spaces).  So that would mean they're defined, right?

Answer (score 0):

Tested on FF3 and Chrome.

```
tn_top_performers[tn_counter]=tn_top_performers[tn_counter].replace(/ /g,"+");
```

Edit: Don't forget the " "(space) between the forward slashes.